# Conditional $push with a single query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the document schema in a collection called NamedLists:

```
{
    "name":"FOO",
    "items":[
        {"primary":4524013,"secondary":9753847},
        {"primary":4420220},
        {"primary":5317116,"secondary":3838379},
        {"primary":4230616},
        {"primary":7389755,"secondary":3838576}
        ]
}
```

And the rules:

1. The "secondary" field may or may not exist on the objects in the items array
2. A document cannot have objects in its items array which have the same "primary" value
3. No two documents in the "NamedLists" collection may have an identical object in their items arrays

For Example the following is NOT allowed since `{"primary":4420220}` is in two different items arrays. However `{"primary":4420220, "secondary": 7897897 }` would be permitted.

```
{ "name":"FOO", "items":[
    {"primary":4524013,"secondary":9753847},
    {"primary":4420220},
    {"primary":5317116,"secondary":3838379},
    {"primary":4230616},
    {"primary":7389755,"secondary":3838576}
]}

{ "name":"BOO", "items":[
    {"primary":4420220}
]}
```

This query satisfies rule #2 but not #3:

```
db.NamedLists.update({ name: "FOO", { primary: { $ne: 4524013 } },
          { $push: {  items: 4524013 } });
```

Is there a way to $push a new object into a given document's items array only when its primary value (or the whole object itself) does not match an object in another document's items array?

In SQL you could use nested SELECTs to achieve this. MongoDB?

Comment: In MongoDB you will need two different queries. One to count the number of documents that match your criteria and one to update the document if `count < 2`. You may also want to add an unique index to the `items` field.